# Missing span element

Tags: css, html

I have a problem with a `span` element in IE (currently tested against IE9 and IE10). When I open <kbd>F12</kbd> Developer Tools and select that `span` element I can't find it on screen. However, if I manually assign a `background-color` other than `transparent` or `inherit` it is shown at its expected place.

The problem is, that the `span` element is used as *alignment element* for a popup, but since the element is missing, the popup is incorrectly aligned.

I wasn't able to observe that behavior in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BsJp5/5/), yet. And also can't test it in other browsers.

Here is how the significant markup looks like:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <span>
            <input id="in" value="Somename"></input>
            <label for="in">Person surname:</label>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS like shown in the developer tools (except for the `background-color` attributes):

```
#div1 {
    background-color: grey;

    cursor: auto;
    font-family: Thoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000000;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
#div2 {
    background-color: blue;

    cursor: auto;
    font-family: Thoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000000;
}
span {
    /* background-color: red; */

    font-family: Thoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
    /*background-color: transparent;*/

    color: #000000;
    padding: 1px 2px 1px 3px;
    font-family: Thoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b4;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 90%; 
}
label {
    cursor: auto;
    font-family: Thoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000000;
    left: 0px;
    top: -99999px;
    font-size: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Any ideas, why the `span` tag could be missing?

**Maybe I should clarify, I'am not so much interested in a solution (since I already found one), but in an explanation why I observe this different behavior. Both for IE vs Jsfiddle and with vs without background-color.**

I am not responsible for the HTML markup, and can't change that. I have only limited access to change the CSS.

Comment: Did you try to look at the source code (right click - source code), not the source code displayed in the developer tool ?

Comment: define span {display:block;}

Comment: @EtienneArthur looking in the source code for what?

Comment: @RohitAzad Yeah that also works, but doesn't explain the behavior. At least to me.

Comment: span is inline element and you used to inline element and convert you inline element to inline-block or block level ...

Answer (score 0):

Add "**display: block;**" to the span element css.

The span element default display property is **inline** and with this **you can't set width, height, margin or padding** properties. So the span element is not missing but have a 0px width and the height of the line-height of font property.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Either use **display:block** or **float:left**
*Tested on IE9-10*

Also note that: use div instead, span tag is not designed to use like this and not a problem to create another **#div3** unless you have something specific.

```
span {
        background-color: red;
        display:block; /* float:left; */
        font-family: Thoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: left;
        color: #000000;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Definition and Usage**
The `<span>` tag is used to group `inline-elements` in a document.

The `<span>` tag provides no visual change by itself.

The `<span>` tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.

**[more about span](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)**